# ng-change function called multiple times with select-box populated with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created chained (parent-child) select-boxes with hierarchies defined in JSON data. Every select-box object has it's parent select-box object specified, and a array of select-box options, where each option contains option value + parent value. The select-box object also contains selected-option object, which is same object as one of the available select-box option objects. Below is a simplified representation of data:

[image]

I am creating select-boxes dynamically using `ng-options` in "select" tag, and then I am using a custom filter where I filter the retrieved options by matching the parent option value of the option values with the "currently selected value" of its parent object. Basically doing many-to-one mapping from child option values to selected parent value using a custom filter.

**The issue is**, with this structure, I want to put `ng-change` directive on select-box, which will call a controller function to do some stuff. But this function is getting called as many times as the number of select-boxes in one hierarchy (3 in this case, as shown in image). This is causing serious undesired behavior in application.

[Here is the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Sv1infkxh8UMWC22bB1?p=preview), where I have reproduced this issue. I am calling a function on select-box change event to set an associated radio-button with select-box (For example, if some value in Country select-box is selected, the the radio-button of next select-box in hierarchy, i.e. State, should get selected). But due to `setDrillDown` function getting called multiple times, the last radio-button associated with last select-box in hierarchy is getting selected.

Stuck badly due to this issue, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) as [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/aDUIHTbeTecziSxKACch/)
so it will only runs function provided in ngChange when I change the selection. but On initialize phase message stays empty.

I used $timeout as [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/FNBr9TrVoofvMRNjSTaB/) and it works well.

Comment: Thank you, worked great for me. Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works as expected. The `ngChange` is called on model value change, and that's what happens to your selects.

When you change first select box the `ngChange`will be called for `Country`, `State` and `City` because values in each of those will change.
If you select something in the 2nd Select `State` then the `ngChange` would be called for the `State` and `City`.

You will have to think of different approach or parametrizing the onChange methods